# Errors were encountered while processing: libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, dpkg

How can I get rid of this package?

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep libnvidia | awk '{print $2}')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64:
 libcuinj64-10.1:amd64 depends on libcuda1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda-10.1-1; however:
  Package libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda.so.1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is to be removed.
 libcuinj64-10.1:amd64 depends on libcuda1 (>= 418.39) | libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) | libcuda-10.1-1; however:
  Package libcuda1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 which provides libcuda1 is to be removed.
  Package libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda.so.1 is not installed.
  Package libcuda-10.1-1 is not installed.
  Package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 which provides libcuda-10.1-1 is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `pavlos` in Ubuntu IRC channel:

Initially, I did:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep libnvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

Not everything was removed then:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep cuda | awk '{print $2}')

$ sudo dpkg --purge libcuinj64-10.1:amd64
```

Then, again,

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep libnvidia | awk '{print $2}')
```